# Pass variable value from "outside" (eg. command line) when LESS is building

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm using my custom `Bootstrap` Theme for my company's apps. And I need to generate styles with different `@font-size-base` for different apps (for instance some apps need to be more compact, other not). Is there a way to pass variable's value from outside? Or maybe you have other ideas how to handle this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--modify-var` option:

lessc bootstrap.less bootstrap.css --modify-var='font-size-base=10px'

See also: http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-options

The `--modify-var` option as above puts the `@font-size-base: 10px;` declaration at the end of your code. Because of Less uses Lazy loading and last declaration wins for variables the value set with `--modify-var` will be used everywhere in your code (and overwrite any earlier declaration for `@font-size-base` ).